# Column 'username' cannot be null

Tags: codeigniter

I wonder why there is this error message appearing.  Column 'username' cannot be null
?

I set Null to No.

---

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'username' cannot be null
>
> INSERT INTO `login` (`username`, `email`, `password`, `role`) VALUES
>   (NULL, NULL,
>   '$2y$10$FaVW7V1yEDB0NnlmgwPHQ.SQi34ZCXi9ABJDOebDflZ.cqcSwZAoW', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:/Program
>   Files/EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1/eds-www/companygiondaci/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

**views/addusers.php**

```
   <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">

                <?php $this->load->library('form_validation'); ?>

                <?php echo $successmessage; ?>

                <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

                <?php echo form_open('cpages/addusersdb'); ?>

                <div class="widget-box">
                    <div class="widget-title"><h5>Add User</h5></div>
                    <div class="widget-content">

                    <table border="0" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td>USERNAME</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>EMAIL</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>PASSWORD</td>
                            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ROLE</td>
                            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('roles', $options, 'administrator'); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="edit" value="ADD"></td>
                        </tr>                           
                    </table>            
                    </div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
        </div>
```

**models/Mpages.php**

```
public function add_user()
{   
    $options = [
      'roles' => 'administrator',
    ];

    $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

    $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'password' => $hash,
        'role' => $this->input->post('roles')       
    );      

    return $this->db->insert('login', $data);

}
```

Comment: set it to `allow null`

Comment: **allow null is not the solution.** Check and fix the error only solution for this.

Comment: Why are you loading your form validation library in your view? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller You really need to look through the user guide,

Comment: And have your set your username to some thing like varchar 100 and email to something similar

Answer (score 1):

```
    if($this->input->post()) {

            $hash = password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $hash,
                'role' => $this->input->post('roles')       
            ); 
            $this->YOUR_MODEL->add_user($data);
    }
```

This should go into your controller.

And your model function should be like this

```
public function add_user($data)
{     

    return $this->db->insert('login', $data);

}
```